# INVALID_TYPE: Cannot use: ApexClass in this organization

Tags: sandbox, metadata, ant

When I try to download apex classes or triggers via the ant tool, I get the following error:

```
INVALID_TYPE: Cannot use: ApexClass in this organization
```

This was working yesterday, I don't think anything major has changed since then.

I have an Unlimited Org, so this should not be a limitation of that.

This is the simplest build xml I can get to fail:

```
<project basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>


    <target name="bulk">
      <sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" 
        serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" metadataType="ApexClass" 
        retrieveTarget="bulkRetrieve\metadata"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Is this a production org or sandbox org?

Comment: This is a sandbox environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there was an Author Apex permission I needed, which had somehow gotten unset at some point.

Adding this permission to my profile has resolved the issue.